# Jmeter Chromedriver error: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist when executed from remote master machine

Tags: javascript, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, performance-testing, distributed

I'm trying to execute WebDriver sampler script from JMeter with WebDriver  plugin and chrome-driver installed . The JMeter is configured to work in distributed mode. I currently have 2 nodes, one Master and one Slave. 
My script resides on master machine and I'm trying to execute it from Master machine using below command.

`$JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter -n -t recorder1.jmx -r`

I receive this error:

```
2019-03-10 16:18:03,416 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2019-03-10 16:18:03,417 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run with stripAlsoOnError: true
2019-03-10 16:18:03,417 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000
2019-03-10 16:18:03,418 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run with stripAlsoOnError: true
2019-03-10 16:18:03,429 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Creating JMeter engine on host xx.xxx.xxx.xx base '..'
2019-03-10 16:18:03,430 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Remote client host: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
2019-03-10 16:18:03,430 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='..'
2019-03-10 16:18:03,431 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Cleaning previously set properties: {}
2019-03-10 16:18:03,431 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Applying properties {}
2019-03-10 16:18:03,431 INFO o.a.j.e.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Running test
2019-03-10 16:18:03,437 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2019-03-10 16:18:03,438 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-03-10 16:18:03,504 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2019-03-10 16:18:03,504 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2019-03-10 16:18:03,504 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-03-10 16:18:03,504 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false
2019-03-10 16:18:03,507 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-03-10 16:18:03,507 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-03-10 16:18:03,508 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: xx.xxx.xxx.xx-Thread Group 1-1
2019-03-10 16:18:03,649 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 4.15.0-1033-aws x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 111 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'jmeter-slave', ip: '10.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-1033-aws', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488) ~[?:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:122) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543) ~[?:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:74) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:21) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:220) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:762) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) [jorphan.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:995) [jorphan.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) [jorphan.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:730) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:718) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [?:?]
2019-03-10 16:18:03,952 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'jp@gc - LoadWidgetAllInOne'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:62) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [?:?]
2019-03-10 16:18:03,957 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: xx.xxx.xxx.xx-Thread Group 1-1
2019-03-10 16:18:03,957 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: xx.xxx.xxx.xx-Thread Group 1-1
2019-03-10 16:18:03,969 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-03-10 16:18:03,969 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Test Ended on xx.xxx.xxx.xx
2019-03-10 16:18:03,969 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Test Ended on xx.xxx.xxx.xx
2019-03-10 16:18:03,970 INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Test Ended on xx.xxx.xxx.xx
2019-03-10 16:18:03,970 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Test Ended on xx.xxx.xxx.xx
2019-03-10 16:18:03,971 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Test has ended on host xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

JMeter-Server runs under ubuntu user on Slave instance. 
I execute my test from Master machine also with ubuntu user. I saw that if chromedriver is executed with superuser it can cause the same issue like I have, but it's not the case.

The strangest thing is that if I execute the same script in headless mode it works fine. 
Also if I execute the same script from GUI or from command line on slave machine it also works fine without errors.

Installed:

- EC2 instance with Ubuntu 18.04
- apache-jmeter-5.1
- ChromeDriver 2.45.615355
- jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar

Any ideas?

I also saw possible solution in: 
[org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d)

It's recommended there to add this code:

```html
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","pathto\\chromedriver.exe");    
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get(url);
```

but how do I change chromedriver options before is is initialised in Chrome Driver Config step in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

1. According to what I see at [ChromeDriver downloads page](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads):

   ```
   Supports Chrome v70-72
   ```

   so make sure that Chrome version installed in Ubuntu is in the supported range
2. Given the OS is Ubuntu **server** it should not have GUI while Chrome requires a [DISPLAY](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch35_08.htm) to run at, either real or [virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb). In both cases you should have DISPLAY variable defined and pointing to the real or virtual display.
3. So first of all log into the machine **exactly as you when running JMeter slave** and launch `/usr/bin/google-chrome` as `ubuntu` user. If it starts without issues - you should be good to go, if not - you will need to fix the browser launching prior to attempting to use it from JMeter. You can double check the result of browser execution by verifying [exit status](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) - running the next command:

   ```
   echo $?
   ```

   if you see `0` - you're fine, if not - you have a problem.

Comment: Dmitri T, Thanks a lot for your response! 
Regarding #1: I have chrome version 72.03626.121

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! 
Regarding #1: I have chrome version 72.03626.121. I tried to change chromedriver to chromedriver=72.0.3626.69, it gives me the same results. 

#2,3 I have VNC/X11 installed on the machine. It opens chrome browser if I execute `/usr/bin/google-chrome` command while I'm in VNC screen.